# Замена символов в строке Java

Tags: java, строки

Метод `string = string.replace("a", "b");` заменит все буквы. Но что если нужно заменить только отдельно стоящие? То есть`"а"` мы меняем, а `"aa"` остается себе стоять. Есть ли способ как-то это реализовать?

Comment: есть. Погуглите про regular expressions

Comment: добавьте пробелы `(" a ", " b ")`

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь регулярным выражением: `(?<!a)a(?!a)` , при этом стоящие рядом символы "a" как "aaaa" пропускаются.

- `(?<!a)` любой символ не "а" до символа "а"
- `a` сам символ "а", который заменяем
- `(?!a)` любой символ не "а", после символа "а"

  Пример кода как использвать

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String testString = "amaaaamaaaamkkjhatapa";
      System.out.println(testString.replaceAll("(?<!a)a(?!a)", "."));
  }
  ```

Вывод в консоль `.maaaamaaaamkkjh.t.p.`

Comment: Прошу прощения за наглость, но "а" была взята просто для примера. Как это применить к любым символам? Или я слишком много хочу?

Comment: Можете поменять на любой другой символ `(?<!b)b(?!b)`, заменит только отдельно стоящие `b` , или замените на любой другой символ. А лучше добавьте более реальные примеры.

Comment: Подставить другой символ я и сам бы догадался, благодарю за столь низкую оценку моего интеллекта. Я спрашивал нельзя ли его,этот способ, сделать универсальным. Впрочем, уже решил проблему своими силами

Comment: Из вопроса и комментариев не могу предположить как сделать универсальным, и какие задачи нужно решать...  Ну и добавьте ответ Вашего решения, интересно посмотреть))